# Why is neutralizing important when carrying out the Benedict test?

Tags: experiment, sugar

When testing for non-reducing sugars, acid is added, then the solution is boiled, then it is neutralized, [benedict solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedict%27s_reagent) is added and then it is boiled again. Why is neutralizing the solution important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benedict's reagent is used mainly to test the presence of reducing sugars.

However, it can also be used to test non-reducing sugars indirectly. For that to happen, non-reducing sugars are first converted to reducing sugars by breaking glycosidic bonds in the presence of acid (ex: HCl).

Now, the next step is to check for the presence of reducing sugars using Benedict's reagent. Before adding our reagent, **neutralization is done because the benedict's reagent requires an alkaline environment to work properly**.

After neutralization only, the benedict's test proceeds further.

Note -> Since, Benedict's reagent is an alkaline solution, so the test solution is only neutralized and not made alkaline in nature.

For more info -- *https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-steps-testing-non-reducing-sugar-704998*